# Rigging & Exporting: Non-Deforming Character Problem

Tags: rigging, export, unreal-engine

So I've recently tried to learn how to make my own armatures for meshes, and I still don't know if I'm even connecting the armature to the mesh right.

One of the main problems that is causing me so much trouble is that the mesh I'm making isn't really a mesh. I don't want the character I'm making to deform so I just went out on a whim and made each piece of the mesh a separate object. ie. UpperTorso, LowerTorso. etc. The blockiness of the character is just the style I went for.

I'm trying to rig it for UE4. That on its own has had ALOT of problems which I'm currently trying to figure out. When trying to export character + armature, I export it as an fbx file, Hopefully, that's right.

I'm still a novice at blender and Unreal engine, At least in the armature and mesh exporting aspect, I have no clue if I did it right and it would be nice if someone could try and point me in some type of direction.
I am willing to start over the whole project, I just need to know what I need to go for to reach my desired goal of the character and where I want to import it to.

File link: http://www.filedropper.com/ue4charactertest3_1

Comment: For future reference please try to keep only one question per post, ask as many as needed. FBX is probably the only correct format for game engines, that supports armatures and animations. For "blocky" or "non deformable" characters you may separate your body parts into different objects, or you may also keep them as a single object and just weight paint them so each separate element is only influenced by one bone.

Comment: Oh! sorry for having 2 questions for this post. I'm new to this website.